# is there a way to use $ after calling noConflict()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use noConflict() for my source code like this because had lot of problem with including duplicate jquery.js from other source codes in my program:

> var $m = jQuery.noConflict();
>
> $m.getJSON(........

problem is that when I call noConflict(), $ will not works. I know I can change $ to JQuery to fix this. but we have lot of custom code from others and this is not possible to change all source codes.

is there a way to recover that? I tried this but not working:

> var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: You should get rid of the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the other code, wrap it in an IIFE closure that binds `jQuery` to a parameter called `$`:

```
(function($) {
     ...
})(jQuery);
```

If you do *not* have access to the other code, you could try to temporarily set `$` to point to your "no-conflict" instance of jQuery:

```
var _tmp = window.$;   // save old value
window.$ = $m;         // or window.$ = window.jQuery

// invoke and/or load other code here
...

window.$ = _tmp;       // restore previous value
```

Comment: Just noting that the second code block must be invoked synchronously.

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, that's probably true in most circumstances.

Comment: @exim I don't know of any reason why it wouldn't, assuming it works at all in your case.

Comment: I tested on ff,ie,chrome,opera and works great :) not sure will work on safari or not. but thanks this is what I need

Answer (score 3):

Use a *function expression*.

```
(function ($) {
    // code using $ for jQuery
}(jQuerysVariable));
```

Comment: That's usually called an IIFE.

Comment: IIFE stands for "immediately invoked **function expression**"

Comment: I do not what to touch other source codes. need a way to recover $